# Mysql Left Join Condition on column value starts with

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, left-join

I am trying to left join two different tables depending on which character a value in column `Type` starts with.

For example:
If the value of column `type` starts with `'s'` => Left Join table `a`
If the value of column `type` starts with `'g'` => Left Join table `b`

How do I create this condition?

Comment: I can't think why you'd want to do this on a well-structured database!?!

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is a 15 years old database, not well structured and I need to add some queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can try below by applying condition in ON Clause

```
select * from tablename x
left join tableA y on x.id=y.id and x.type like 's%'
left join tableB z on x.id=z.id and x.type like 'g%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name t 
    LEFT JOIN A ON LEFT(t.type, 1) = 's' AND t.id = A.tid
    LEFT JOIN B ON LEFT(t.type, 1) = 'g' AND t.id = B.tid
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22c9ad0fb6ae207584f09bcdbba1912b)